# Why do I get this error 'binding to target method' using Delegate.CreateDelegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

The Run2 method is run. But the Run method is not run. What is the reason ?
The only difference between two methods is because parameter.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    public IEnumerable<T> TestMethod<T>(int i)
    {
        //do something
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> TestMethod2<T>()
    {
        //do something
        return null;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Run()
    {
        MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("TestMethod").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyClass));
        var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEnumerable<MyClass>>), this, mi);
        var list = (IEnumerable<MyClass>)del.DynamicInvoke(0);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Run2()
    {
        MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("TestMethod2").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyClass));
        var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEnumerable<MyClass>>), this, mi);
        var list = (IEnumerable<MyClass>)del.DynamicInvoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEnumerable<MyClass>>), this, mi);
```

You've said to bind your method to a `Func<IEnumerable<MyClass>>` delegate, but the actual method should be `Func<int, IEnumerable<MyClass>>` (because of the `int` argument to `TestMethod`).  The following should correct it:

```
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, IEnumerable<MyClass>>), this, mi);
```