# Getting 'Error binding to target method.' for Delegate.CreateDelegate() in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, delegates

I have a custom action filter in MVC3 application

```
public class CustomActionFilter:ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> AdditionalCheck { get; set; }

        public CustomActionFilter()
        {

        }

        public CustomActionFilter(Type declaringType, string methodName)
        {
            MethodInfo method = declaringType.GetMethod(methodName);
            AdditionalCheck = (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>), method);

        }
    }
```

I want to use this as addition check that can be provided on an Action. The problem is it throws '**Error binding to target method**'. I created a console application and it was able to create the delegate. Is this a problem in web projects?

I also tried:

```
AdditionalCheck = (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>)Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>), method);
```

Already gone through the similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026259/error-binding-to-target-method) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939108/why-do-i-get-this-error-binding-to-target-method-using-delegate-createdelegate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it solves your problem, but the code you provided wouldn't work this way, since you have no instance of a target (of the declaring type), where you want to invoke your method.

When you change it into:

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private object _target;

    public Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool> AdditionalCheck { get; set; }

    public CustomActionFilter()
    {
    }

    public CustomActionFilter(Type declaringType, string methodName)
    {
        MethodInfo method = declaringType.GetMethod(methodName);
        _target = Activator.CreateInstance(declaringType);
        AdditionalCheck = (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>),_target, method);
    }
}
```

then it works in my test project (MVC 3).

But I'd recommend to rethink your code structure, maybe you could find another way, without such a use of Reflection.

Hope this helps.